# success is not a function angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to make simple String webApi get request by angularjs

I do not know what is the problem

Is there any better way to get simple string from webApi?

This the error

```
angular.min.js:2TypeError: currentYear.thisYear(...).success is not a function
```

web api

```
// GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        string time =  DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        return time;
    }
```

Service:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var timeService = angular.module('timeService', ['ngResource']);

timeService.factory('currentYear', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        thisYear: function () {
            return $http.get('/api/year/');
        }
    };
}]); 
})();
```

Controller

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('saniehha').controller('currentYearController', currentYearController);

currentYearController.$inject = ['$scope','currentYear'];

function currentYearController($scope, currentYear) {
    var value = currentYear.thisYear().success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
$scope.currentYear = value;
}
})();
```

Comment: tyr with .then instead of success

Comment: Side note: In general, I would avoid calling a variable containing a promise `value`. It's misleading.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do you mean I use retValue instead of value?

Comment: I just mean "value" suggests it actually contains the value you're requesting with `thisYear`, but it doesn't, it contains a *promise* of that value. Just FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Angular 1.6, the `.success`  and `.error` callback functions are removed from the API. [They were deprecated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.14/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice) in at least 1.4.

You should use `.then` instead of `.success`, as `$http` methods return a `promise` object:

```
var value= currentYear.thisYear().then(function (data) {
    $scope.currentYear = data.data;
});
```

You could use that to chain it further.

[$http's deprecated custom callback methods - success() and error() Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#http-due-to)

Comment: The data is object not string. but data.data is string

Comment: if then executed $scope.currentYear = value; not triggered!!

Comment: @cinoheeenayati what do you mean?